# How do I use a Java .class file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a homework assignment that requires us to use functions in a provided .class file. I'm trying to add it in Eclipse, but I'm not having any luck.

The .class file is not part of a package, and I am not submitting it with my .java files. This means I cannot change the directory of the .class file, it needs to be in the same directory with all my .java files. I don't think I can add an external class folder with these requirements. Adding the file to a .jar is also out of the question.

How can I get my java code to recognize the methods in the .class file?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the class folder where your .class file is located. To do that go to the Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Class Folder

Comment: That did not work. The .class file is currently in the src folder. I won't have control over where the .class file ends up because I'm only turning in .java files and my professor is using his copy of the .class file

Comment: You need to put the class files in the right directory structure that is the same with its package. In general, you should have separate directory within your project to just put this class file instead of having it with your source. When you turn in your .java files, all you need to do is state your assumption where you put .class files or better yet, just zip up the project directory. I think your professor would understand.

Comment: InfestedTaco, the solution momo posted is the correct one. You need to put this .class in a separate folder and then add the folder to the build path for your Eclipse project. If its not working then you are probably incorrect that the class is not part of a (Java) package.